# In WCF can I expose webHttpBinding Restfull and NetNamedPipeBinding at the same time which is hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf

Am creating a WCF service which will be hosted in IIS 7. Can I expose webHttpBinding for Json communication and also netNamedPipeBinding for internal to the system

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not allowed to have two types of protocol on single WCF service in one hosting process on IIS. The reason is that for `WebHttpBinding` you would need to use `AspnetcompatibilityMode` which allows WCF to be hosted side by side in Asp.net app domain and allows functionalities like `Routing`, access to `HttpContext.Current`.
Other binding types won't be supported with other types of biding if you have `Aspnetcompatiblitymode` enabled. For more details read the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682(v=vs.110).aspx).